# Wrap column Table to new row on small screens using bootstrap

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have a table on one of my pages using bootstrap for my responsive design.  When on a small screen I want to move one of the columns below the other two.  Is this possible?

as you can see there are 5 columns below when on desktop. While on small screens I want the note column to go below the other columns.

```
@foreach (var item in Model.TicketNotes.OrderBy(m => m.TicketNoteDate).Reverse())
    {
          <tr>
               <td style="text-align: center">
                   @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TicketNoteDate)
               </td>
               <td>
                   @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserNote.FullName)
               </td>
               <td style="text-align: center" class="hidden-xs">
                   @if (item.PublicFlag == true)
                   {
                       <span>Public</span>
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       <span>Private</span>
                   }
              </td>
              <td>
                   @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Note)
              </td>
              <td>
                   <div>
                      @if (item.AttachmentName != null)
                      {
                         string path = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MediaFolder"] + "/Tickets/" + ViewBag.ticketNumber + "/" + item.AttachmentName;
                             if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
                             {
                                  @Html.ActionLink(item.AttachmentName, "ViewAttachment", new { controller = "File", filePath = path, fileName = item.AttachmentName }, new { target = "_blank" });
                             }
                      }
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        @*<td>
                            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditTicketNote", "TicketNote", null,
                            new { id = item.TicketNoteId, ticketNumber = Model.TicketNumber, returnUrl = Model.ReturnUrl, SearchCategory = Model.SearchCategory, SearchStatus = Model.SearchStatus,  
                                SearchTechnician = Model.SearchTechnician, SearchUser = Model.SearchUser, page = ViewBag.page })
                        </td>*@
                    </tr>
```